# Baking texture atlas from objects that have UVs unwrapped using a different method

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I have 3 objects with different materials, texture, and UVs. I want to bake color data to one single texture to bring in a Game engine.

I've tried unwrapping all objects on a separate UV map and baking them in a texture (thas was a selected node in every object's material). The problem is I've used smart UV unwrap for all selected objects, in order to get all in the same map, while some on **initial UVs were created by unwrapping from view**.
Textures are in such format that I cant easily do a proper unwrap with seams.